# How to stitch two videos side by side using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editor, encoding, concatenation

I want to create a video that consists of same video encoded at 2 different quality levels, half of each stitched side by side. Basically, like this image, right half of the video is the right half of one video and left half from the left-half of the other video. The aim is to show the visual difference of the videos. How can I achieve this using `ffmpeg` (or any other software)?

[image]

Comment: crop overlay: `ffmpeg -i "low.mp4" -i "mid.mp4" -filter_complex "
color=white[c];
[c][0]scale2ref[bg][v0];
[v0]crop=iw/2-1:ih:0:0[v0];
[1]crop=iw/2+1:ih:iw-ow:0[v1];
[bg][v0]overlay=eof_action=endall[b0];
[b0][v1]overlay=x=W-w:eof_action=endall,setsar=1;
" out.mp4`